# Retrieving objects from existing R-code in Shiny with source() function

Tags: r, object, shiny, output

I run into two problems retrieving multiple objects from a source file that depend on reactive values specified in the ui part of Shiny. I have already written a full R code (consisting of multiple source.R files) that will perform an optimization. I would like my Shiny app to take several input values for the existing optimization, and call the first source file with these input values, perform the optimization and output all the information I need to make nice graphs, tables and export files to xls. The following is example code of what I am attempting right now:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(wellPanel( 
          fluidRow(
            radioButtons(inputId="a", label="Period select", 
                         choices=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                         selected="B", inline=TRUE),

            fileInput(inputId="file1", "Upload XLSX file"),
                      actionButton("go", "Go")
            ))))


 server <- function(input, output){

  dataxlsx = reactive({
    if (input$go > 0) { 
      infile = input$file1  

      if (is.null(infile))
        return(NULL)

      read.xlsx(infile$datapath, 1)

    }})

  panda <- reactive({
    a <- input$a # is this necessary for all parameters used in source file?
    source("./testsource.R", local=TRUE)})

  output$plottest <- renderPlot({hist(panda[[2]])})
# I have made and returned a list with three objects in the source file

}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

1) The first problem I encounter is how these input values will be send to the source file. Is any previously defined input value readily available to the code in the source file? Or do I have to define these again? For example input$a defined in the ui part, will this be automatically available if source file uses solely ‘a’ as a single value?'

2) The second problem deals with the actual reactive call of the source file. This optimization could take a long time, depending on which input values are chosen. Therefore, I only want to run the optimization once with the chosen parameters in the input, then I preferably want the source file to return or save all the objects I need (such as tables, printed text, figures and excel files that are produced) all at once and later call them when needed with Shiny code. Is there a good option of doing this (do I need to write a ‘return’ function in the source file??

Any thoughts or help on how to specify the output of a source file so that it entails multiple objects are very much appreciated!!

Comment: 1 - Nothing is sent to the source file, instead the source file is loaded within the environment (so the `a`variable will be accessible). But I would recommend defining a function in the source file and calling it with the argument a

Comment: What would be the advantage of using a function? That it can return output?

Comment: You can put the instruction  `source` at the beginning of the code, and use the function at different places.

Comment: Thank you, I will see if the whole code can be written as a function, but it is a very large code so any other suggestions/ideas are very welcome